# How can I programmatically access old revisions of a project in an Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: eclipse, subversive, egit

I'm writing an Eclipse plug-in that visualizes the history of a project, so I'm looking for ways to programmatically use the CVS/SVN/Git plug-ins in Eclipse to get the source-code history of a project. Ideally, I would want to re-use the existing Wizards to set up the repository, and then somehow grab all the code / tags and do my visualization.

(I'm familiar with Eclipse plug-in development, but I've never used any of the Team Provider APIs.)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the RepositoryProvider class. The documentation in the help in the Platform Plugin Devloper guide under Team support is pretty good.